# FFmpeg not recording audio during screen capture

Tags: sound, microphone, ffmpeg

I'm using the script below to run FFmpeg on Ubuntu 10.10. I followed these [instructions](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=786095&highlight=install+ffmpeg+x264) to install FFmpeg & x264.

While `ffmpeg` does capture the screen it does not capture the mic audio. I've checked that the mic works via *"System Preferences"*. Anyone have any ideas on what the problem(s) could be and suggestions on how to resolve this issue? Thanks.

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i hw:0,0 -f x11grab -r 30 -s $(xwininfo -root |  grep 'geometry' | awk '{print $2;}') -i :0.0 -acodec pcm_s16le -vcodec  libx264 -vpre lossless_ultrafast -threads 0 -y screen-capture.mkv
```

Comment: Have you checked Sound Preferences to ensure that your Mic is the current input source?

Comment: I had problems with alsa blocking sometimes.  have you tried oss and dev/dsp?

Comment: Helloooo, are you there?

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards